# when i rewrite scroll bar css property , then the resize icon of textarea styles has changed

Tags: javascript, html, css

**when i re-write scroll bar css property , the resize icon of  textarea styles has changed**

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background: transparent!important;
}
```

I try to reset to original scroll , the resize icon of  textarea looks normal.

[image]

Comment: So do u want to hide the resize icon? What is the question?

Comment: nope... not hide

Comment: Can u clarify more about question _"resize icon of textarea styles has changed"_ Dnt understand what changed